# wget 400 bad request

Tags: wget, openstreetmap

i'm trying to download the data from OSM, this [guide](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Download) says that i can do this with following command:

```
wget -O muenchen.osm "http://api.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/map?bbox=11.54,48.14,11.543,48.145"
```

This command works fine, but when i'm trying to download my map:

```
wget -O muenchen.osm "http://api.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/map?bbox=34.3893,49.5277,34.7195,49.6727"
```

it says:

```
Resolving api.openstreetmap.org... 193.63.75.100, 193.63.75.99, 193.63.75.103, ...
Connecting to api.openstreetmap.org|193.63.75.100|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 400 Bad Request
2013-12-19 11:47:41 ERROR 400: Bad Request.
```

Any ideas what am i doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get a 400 error "When any of the node/way/relation limits are crossed" ([source](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API_v0.6#Retrieving_map_data_by_bounding_box%3a_GET_.2Fapi.2F0.6.2Fmap)). Try to make your bounding box smaller.

Comment: Thanks, any ideas how to get permission to use bigger bounds?

Comment: Have a look at the section "Huge amount of data": http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Downloading_data

Comment: Thanks, you're life saviour:)

Comment: Explanation: The main API is *not* suited for bulk-downloading large data. There are various other possibilities instead.